# Is it possible to dynamically allocate a temporary variable in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

Is it possible to dynamically allocate a temporary variable in C++ ?

I want to do something like that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string* foo()
{
  std::string ret("foo");
  return new std::string(ret);
}

int main()
{
  std::string *str = foo();
  std::cout << *str << std::endl;                                                                                                           
  return 0;
}
```

This code works but the problem is I have to create an other string in order to return it as a pointer. Is there a way to put my temporary/local variable inside my heap without recreate an other object ?

Here is an illustration of how I would do that :

```
std::string* foo()
{
  std::string ret("foo");
  return new ret; // This code doesn't work, it is just an illustration
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `std::string foo() { return "foo"; }`?  The copy is all but guaranteed to be elided.

Comment: +1 to James, but avoid 'all but' it's confusing for us, non-native english speakers.

Comment: My code is much more complex than that, the pointer constraint is not avoidable.

Comment: Then, maybe, a smart pointer will help, especially since you need to be able to free that variable in many cases.

Comment: @kl94: If your example is not indicative of your issue, can you provide an example that shows why you absolutely must return heap-allocated memory?

Comment: @NicolBolas It's simply a constraint, and once again unavoidable. Finally I've used what I've wrote in my first exemple. But I still asking myself if it is possible to "redefine" a temporary variable for a head-allocated var. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes there is, it's called smart pointers:

```
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<std::string> foo()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<std::string>("foo");
}

// Use like this:
using namespace std;
auto s = foo();     // unique_ptr<string> instead of auto if you have an old standard.
cout << *s << endl; // the content pointed to by 's' will be destroyed automatically
                    // when you stop using it
```

Edit: without changing the return type:

```
std::string* foo()
{
    auto s = std::unique_ptr<std::string>("foo");
    // do a lot of stuff that may throw

    return s.release(); // decorellate the string object and the smart pointer, return a pointer
                        // to the string
}
```

Comment: (I assume you _want_ dynamically allocated memory, if you don't then return by value as mentionned by James McNellis)

Comment: It's a nice way, but is there a way to do that without change the return type ? (std::string *) ? I was thinking about dynamic_cast but I cannot get it to work properly..

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use your solution because I use an old standard. But thank you for your help.

Comment: In case you can use boost, boost provides boost::unique_ptr in the old standard which has inspired the new standard.

Comment: @J.N.: No, Boost does not provide `unique_ptr`. It provides `shared_ptr` and `scoped_ptr`, but `unique_ptr` requires move semantics, which didn't exist when Boost did most of its stuff. And even Boost.Move doesn't provide a `unique_ptr` implementation. You should suggest `auto_ptr`, which is a perfectly functional (though dangerous if you don't know what you're doing) smart pointer.

Comment: @J.N.  Finally I've used what I've wrote in my first exemple. But I still asking myself if it is possible to "redefine" a temporary variable for a head-allocated variable with old standard. Thanks anyway for your help, cya. I accept your answer because it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
std::string* foo()
{
    std::string * ret = new std::string("foo");
    // do stuff with ret
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: of course, this code works. At start, I've done this but I have to do some stuff with my var. But I have a lot of exception to check and I have to delete my var before each throw. So I've decided to create a local variable, then after test, return a pointer of it.

Comment: To complete my answer, smart pointers are guaranteed to be deleted even if you throw.